# In an iterative process, how does one simply bypass a step producing an error?

Tags: warning-messages, compile, iteration

This is undoubtedly rather elementary, but the remedy escapes me presently (and does not, as far as I can see, readily appear in Help).

I'm engaged in an iterative process with several computations at each iteration, and for rare steps I generate:

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0] encountered

and

CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression ComplexInfinity should be a "machine-size real number

and

CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation

I would just simply like to bypass such steps (while recording--though not essential--their  specific numbers).

How might I proceed?

Comment: How and why do you get `CompiledFunction` errors? Why do you compile uncompilable code (indicated by `CompiledFunction::cfex`)?

Answer (score 1):

The following example fits the description in the OP; however, the description is so vague, I have my doubts about the helpfulness of the example:

```
cf = Compile[{x}, 1/y /. y -> (x - 2), 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"RuntimeErrorHandler" -> Function[Throw[$Failed[#]]]}];
Table[Catch@cf[xx], {xx, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The default `"RuntimeErrorHandler"` is to evaluate the uncompiled expression; changing the `"RuntimeErrorHandler"` does not change the text of the error message.

Comment: I guess OP is some acronym for the question posed. This is all very sophisticated, and somewhat beyond my full understanding. I guess my question was how does one straightforwardly move on to the next iteration if such problems or any other errors arise. In other words, "let's just forget about this step, we have enough results without it".

Comment: @PaulB.Slater (1) Yes, "OP" = "Original Post" (or in other contexts, "Original Poster", i.e. the author). (2) To skip the step, try changing `Throw[$Failed[#]]` to `Throw[Nothing]`.

Comment: In general `Catch[...; Throw[value];...]` is a standard way to return a `value` from deep within code (for instance, from inside a loop, inside a subroutine such as inside the compiled environment WVM in this case). It is commonly used to stop a computation when an exceptional situation occurs, which is exactly your use-case here.

Comment: Thanks! So, how can I skip the subsequent computations--which would contaminate my cumulative results--in the error-producing step and move onto the next iteration (bump the loop parameter up by 1)?

Comment: Per the first comment of Michael E2 above, what might one do rather than "skipping the step" in question, instead directly Goto another statement, several statements removed from the error-producing one?  That is skip those intervening statements that would try to process the erroneous results (leading to Indeterminate outcomes).

Comment: The execution will continue after the `Catch` (`Catch[...Throw[value];..]; <continues here>...`).  E.g. `Module[{acc = {}, xx = -1}, 
 Catch[While[xx <= 3, acc = {acc, cf[xx]}; xx++]]; Flatten@acc]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tracked down ("divide-and-conquer") the specific iteration (16,630,333) at which the error messages occurred--and found that a certain number, generated through a process involving random numbers, was testing as equal to 0. The log of this number then yielded the ComplexInfinity in question. So, now I'm checking at each subsequent iteration for this phenomenon. Hopefully, this will fully solve the specific problem at hand (but perhaps not the more general problem posed--of simply omitting/skipping iterations at which [arbitrary] errors occur, without necessarily pinpointing their nature).

In the continuing series of iteration, things ran smoothly until iteration 46,894,463 (which I had to track down between 46 and 48 million) when the same error messages were generated. However, my testing for 0 
to bypass the step did not now succeed. The function I was compiling at this iteration had the value {0., 0., 0., Indeterminate, 0., 0., Indeterminate, 0., Indeterminate, Indeterminate}. So, I went back and further incorporated a test for the entries of the vector being 0. But, this to my surprise and puzzlement did not succeed in bypassing the step. So, at this point, I'm simply explicitly bypassing iteration 46,894,463.

Undoubtedly, as MichaelE is suggesting, some use of the Throw and Catch commands should be able to address my problem in general. But I don't sufficiently appreciate their use at this point--but will try to do so. Until that point, I may have to simply follow an ad hoc procedure--that is tracking down the "rogue" iteration and going back and explicitly excluding it.